# How to migrate between PubSub subscriptions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a PubSub topic with a Subscription A and a code that reads from A. What I need to do is to create Subscription B and switch my code from A to B. I also have limitations which are a) do not miss any message and b) avoid duplications (processing the same message twice).

The naive approach would be something like:

1. Create new subscription B
2. Stop old code that consumes from A
3. Start new code that consumes from B

Problem of this approach is that messages acked from A between steps 1. and 2. won't be acked from B, so we will process them twice after step 3.

Ideally, it would be nice to be able to "mirror" A and B somehow, so message acked in A is also acked in B, but afaik PubSub doesn't have anything like that.

What would be the best approach to do this migration?

Comment: Fyi, unless you have Exactly-once delivery turned on (which is in beta, and 
comes with a performance cost), you can (and will) get duplicate messages. So this processing the same message twice should not matter in the first place.

Comment: That being said you could just do an update to the consumer to store the acked message id's somewhere persistent. And use that to ignore already processed messages. After all doubles are gone you can turn it off again.